# Is there a way to set up a nightly scheduled downtime for maintenance in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, maintenance-mode

I need to clean up disks nightly and I want to schedule a downtime. Yes I know about the ability to have individual agents do cleanups before starting but I need to do some very specialized cleanups so I need the downtime. Just to clarify - I need to schedule a downtime for the AGENTS. Thanks.

Comment: What are you looking to cleanup? Is it in TeamCity directories or elsewhere on the agent?

Comment: When our hard drives start to fill up, I disable all the build agents manually and run a powershell script (manually)to clean out the directories.

Answer (score 1):

Teamcity does not provide this functionality directly but you can use REST API to disable agents during your maintenance. That way if any build is scheduled during your maintenance it will stay in the queue until the maintenance is done or executed on another agent if available.

For disabling you can run

```
curl -v --basic --user USERNAME:PASSWORD --request PUT "http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/agents/id:3/enabled" --data false --header "Content-Type: text/plain"
```

And to enable

```
curl -v --basic --user USERNAME:PASSWORD --request PUT "http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/agents/id:3/enabled" --data true --header "Content-Type: text/plain"
```

For more info see this [discussion](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5462246#5462246).

Comment: the problem is that is I have agents already running, I cannot disable them. And the REST API is a manual process. What I really need is the ability to create a maintenance window from 2AM to 4AM, which would prevent any agents from running - give agents running at 2AM an hour to complete, and at 3AM, run a powershell script to clean up all the drives.

Comment: If your agents are running a job all day long you might be better off with some task scheduler and not a CI server. Anyway if you want a built in function it does not exist. Any solution would need some level of scripting. By the way you can disable a running agent. The task will finish normally.

Comment: Good to know I can disable the agent while its running. So now that I think about it more - is there a way to 'auto-disable' all the agents at a given time? I can then set a cron job for my powershell to run after the auto-disable.

Comment: No, what you can do However is to define a TC configuration that runs you clean up job add scheduled trigger to run it at the time you need on all agents. That way you can be sure no other task is running on agents since agents run one task at a time.

Comment: So what you are saying is run my cleanup as just another job in TC.

Answer (score 0):

In Team City 8, it's under Administration: Build History Cleanup.

It lets you schedule when it should run and what it should clean up.

Comment: Question is for agents, not server.

Comment: That option is for individual build agents - not a system wide shutdown.